# javascript-scrollTop() acts differently while used in variable and used directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web page which is intend to load contents while scroll to the bottom of the page.
I'm new to javascript and the project is based on `Flask` framework.
When I used

```
top = $(window).scrollTop();
alert(top);
```

echoed

```
[object Window]
```

I'm using `chrome` and `safari` to test the project.
However, when I'm using

```
alert($(window).scrollTop());
```

the page returned the position of the scroll bar.
I think these two ways are the same. Why two results?

Answer (score 0):

The variable named `top` in your first code sample is using a global variable that refers to [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top), which is an object of type Window. In the second code sample, you are not using that variable, so you see the expected result.

You should either rename your variable or use `var` to avoid referencing the global, like so:

```
var top = $(window).scrollTop();
```

My suggestion would be to do both:

```
var topPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
```